# Cannot drop index {index_name}: needed in a foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

I want to drop an index, but I can't because is used in another table, but I can't find where

```
ALTER TABLE t_course DROP INDEX user_id
```

Is there a way to know where it is used ?

Comment: check the indexes with the data base management tool you use. They have both the local field and the table and field they referencing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the other table that the constraints reference:

```
select COLUMN_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME, REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME, REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME
from information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
where TABLE_NAME = 't_course';
```

Take a look at the `REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME` returned from the above query.

Comment: i am getting same error and this query returns null REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME, and REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME